# Gensim models.LdaMulticore() not executing when imported trough other file

Tags: python, machine-learning, gensim, lda

The code found test.py runs correctly. But when importing test.py in the test2.py file the line that creates the LdaMulticore model seems to be stuck.

I have added the example code to illustrate the problem. Is there a solution for this?

test.py:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from gensim import corpora, models
from gensim.matutils import Sparse2Corpus
import time

data_clean = ["This is the first example document.","This is the second example document.","This is the third and last exaple document"]

vectorizer = CountVectorizer(analyzer='word', ngram_range=(1,1), min_df = 0.0001, max_df=0.8,stop_words = 'english')
matrix =  vectorizer.fit_transform(data_clean)

id2words = dict()
for k, v in vectorizer.vocabulary_.iteritems():
    id2words[v] = k

train_corpus = Sparse2Corpus(matrix, documents_columns=False)

if __name__ == 'test':
    print "The file is being imported"
    model = models.LdaMulticore(train_corpus ,id2word=id2words,num_topics=10, workers=4)
else:
    print "The file is directly executed"
    model = models.LdaMulticore(train_corpus ,id2word=id2words,num_topics=10, workers=4)
```

test2.py:

```
import test
```

Terminal output : 
[terminal output when running test2.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m8x2V.png)